# If MousePosition is overhoving "X" control then

Tags: .net, vb.net, mouse-position

How I can know if the mouseposition is inside a margin?

I mean for example I have a TrackBar control in my form then I want to know if the mouseposition is overhoving that control.

```
private some sub()...
  if not mouseposition is over MyTrackbar location then
    Do something
  else
    Do nothing
  end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if the mouseposition is overhoving that control.

The [MouseHover event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will tell you that

Comment: I know how to use he mousehover event but I did not think well as it had to do, first create a boolean variable to manage if the mouse is overhoving the control, second in the mousehover event set that variable to "True" and in the mouseleave event set it to "false", well thanks.